# Anyway to have stripes of different textures without making a lot of geometry?

Tags: texturing, materials, uv, edit-mode, geometry

[image][image]

I have 2 materials that have the same texture, but different hue node values. I want to have stripes that are only in specific areas of the mesh and I want to have the orange stripe repeat after every 4 blue tiles. This is the best way I could think off and it's most likely very bad way of doing this. Is there a proper way of doing such a thing?

Comment: The best thing I can think is to make a model with the necessary geometry to facilitate the stripes, then bake a texture map of the setup and apply it to the same model, minus the geometry. An alternative is to have a mix shader combining the two materials, with the mix factor controlled by the position value of a texture co-ordinate. You would probably have to make some nightmarish setup of math and mapping nodes to get the positioning just right though.

Comment: Ya was thinking maybe doing the first one. If I'm making floor for a building and baked the texture, would it be a gigantic texture?

Comment: Not necessarily. Baking yields a "texture atlas" at whatever resolution you set while making it. Usually you want to pick a higher resolution (2048x2048 common) so the final result doesn't come out blurry. Don't fret over the larger texture size though (especially with regards to performance), as baking serves to replace multiple materials, as well as reducing draw calls on the object. You can even go 4K if necessary... but it's probably still best stick to what you can get away with.